# Windows 8 extra Features Requested

Tags: windows, windows-8

Does anybody know a tool or a way to make windows command shell and directory explorer on windows become like the shell and directory explorer on mac.

Explain: I want to label files on the folder explorer on window with different colors so I can know the files I viewed.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwjrng2aEqueZFRFbG1wV3JrdlE/edit
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwjrng2aEqueUWRJTTlpQmo1YzA/edit

Also, I want a shell terminal like mac/linux shell so I can open many terminal windows and do more features than the normal windows command shell

Thanx,

Comment: You can program a new shell, but I'm sure that is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the folder icon in windows.  right click the folder, properties, customize, chang icon.  This way you could make a new icon to show that the folder has been "viewed".

Comment: I don't need that, I want to add colored labels to the files inside a folder

Comment: Windows explorer doesn't work that way..  There are other options like setting the archive flag, but they are usually command line type options and really out of the scope of what you asked for.